# Receiving syntax error on missing ; before statement and receiving reference error on javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hi when I open up the application (code is at bottom of question), straight away I get an error stating:

```
SyntaxError:missing ; before statement
```

The above error shows this line in the view page source:

```
var moduleinfo = 
Notice: Undefined variable: moduleInfo in ... on line 267
```

How can the above error be fixed?

Also in the code below when the user selects a course from the course drop down menu and submits the course, it displays a modules drop down menu but it also gives me another error stating:

```
ReferenceError: validation is not defined
```

The above error shows that this error is in line 1 in the page source which is just a blank line.

My question is that how can both these errors be fixed in the code below:(The order of the code below is the exact order in the application with the php coming first then the javascript, I have also commented on where line 267 is (javascript) for first error and commented where javascript function validation is)

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include('connect.php');
include('noscript.php');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
}


$sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course ORDER BY CourseNo";

$sqlstmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

$sqlstmt->execute();

$sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

$courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

$courseHTML = "";
$courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
$courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

$outputcourse = "";
$hiddencourse = "";

while ($sqlstmt->fetch()) {
    $course     = $dbCourseId;
    $courseno   = $dbCourseNo;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName;
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='" . $course . "'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;

    if (isset($_POST['courses']) && ($_POST['courses'] == $course)) {
        $outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</p>";
        $hiddencourse .= "<p><input type='hidden' id='hiddencourse' value='" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "'></p>";
    }

}

$courseHTML .= '</select>';


?>

<form action="<?php
echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Course: <?php
echo $courseHTML;
?></th>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Course" name="courseSubmit" /></p>
<div id="courseAlert"></div>
<div id="targetdiv"></div>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['courseSubmit'])) {
    //get the form data 
    $coursesdrop = (isset($_POST['courses'])) ? $_POST['courses'] : '';

    $modulequery = "
SELECT
m.ModuleId, m.ModuleNo, m.ModuleName, m.Credits
FROM
Module m
WHERE
m.ModuleId NOT IN (
SELECT cm.ModuleId
FROM Course_Module cm
WHERE cm.CourseId = ?
)
ORDER BY m.ModuleNo
";

    $moduleqrystmt = $mysqli->prepare($modulequery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $moduleqrystmt->bind_param("i", $coursesdrop);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $moduleqrystmt->execute();

    $moduleqrystmt->bind_result($dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbCredits);

    $moduleqrystmt->store_result();

    $modulenum = $moduleqrystmt->num_rows();

    $moduleHTML = '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
    $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

    $moduleInfo = array();

    while ($moduleqrystmt->fetch()) {
        $moduleHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s</option>", $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName) . PHP_EOL;

        $moduleData               = array();
        $moduleData["ModuleId"]   = $dbModuleId;
        $moduleData["ModuleNo"]   = $dbModuleNo;
        $moduleData["ModuleName"] = $dbModuleName;
        $moduleData["Credits"]    = $dbCredits;

        array_push($moduleInfo, $moduleData);

    }


    $moduleHTML .= '</select>';


    $moduleexist = "
<div id='rt-container'>
<form id='moduleExistForm'>
<p><strong>Current Modules</strong></p>
<p>{$moduleSELECT}</p>
</form> 
</div>";

    echo $moduleexist;


}

?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var moduleinfo = <?php echo json_encode($moduleInfo); ?> ; //line 267

        $('#modulesDrop').change(function () {

            var moduleId = $(this).val(),
                moduledata;

            for (var i = 0, l = moduleinfo.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (moduleinfo[i].ModuleId == moduleId) {
                    moduledata = moduleinfo[i];
                }
            }

            var currentindex = $('#credits').val(moduledata.Credits);

        });


    });

//below is the validation() function

    function validation() {

        var isDataValid = true;

        var courseTextO = document.getElementById("coursesDrop");

        var errCourseMsgO = document.getElementById("courseAlert");

        if (courseTextO.value == "") {
            $('#targetdiv').hide();
            $('#moduleForm').hide();
            $('#detailsForm').hide();
            $('#addbtn').hide();
            errCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Course";
            isDataValid = false;
        } else {
            errCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        }

        return isDataValid;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: @TeodorTalov Sorry forgot to comment I have now commented it

Comment: What do you get at the browser? That is where the error is, so no point in showing only the server code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the space in your php line:

`var moduleinfo = <? php echo json_encode($moduleInfo); ?> ;`

To

`var moduleinfo = <?php echo json_encode($moduleInfo); ?> ;`

`<? php` should be together like `<?php`

Comment: Hi, I removed the space but still showing error

Comment: Is it because I put it in document function? As it does not appear until course has been submitted? Or could it be order of code?.... I tried removing document function but still get error

Comment: If the same error persists then it would suggest `<?php echo json_encode($moduleInfo); ?>` holds no information. Have you echo'd `$moduleInfo` to see if it has any thing assigned to it on the JS file?

Comment: I did a var_dump() and it outputted this `array(0) { } `. But I get the same for when I use a similar method in another application and I get no error for that one. Difference with that one though is that the user doesn't have to submit something to see other info on the page, in the other app the user simply selects off the drop down menu and then all the details are viewed. In this app, the user selects a course then submits the page, then the module drop down menu appears after the submit and this is when the var_dump() of the array is shown.

Comment: Ah yeah, If I move `$moduleInfo = array();` above the `if (isset($_POST['courseSubmit'])) {` code then it removes the error. I upvoted your answer but now problem 2 needs to be tackled on the Reference error

Comment: Is your JS included in the file before the form ? Or after it, from what i can guess - the JS function is set in the HTML header right? But browsers work kinda backwards in that, it will read the HTML before the Javascript, effectively meaning it won't find the function.

One solution is to define the function from a windows onload or place the JavaScript after all the HTML.

Comment: The javascript currently is placed after the HTML, do you mean place it before the HTML? So that it goes javascript on top of page and then PHP/HTML after it? At the moment the javascript is below the PHP/HTML code in the <body> tag

Comment: OK this is what I did to solve the reference error, I create another set of <script> tags on top of the page and included `validation()` function at top of page and left the other javascript functions at bottom of the page. So the page contains javascript first, then php/html in middle and then rest of javascript at bottom of page. Thanks for your help best answer :)

Comment: BTW I can see you live in the UK like me, what are you still doing up? haha :)

Comment: Yes you got it, now the function is set "before" hand so it now finds it. I think i worded my previous reply some what backwards, its late after all ^_^